# How do I set up a script to run automatically, whenever my system connects to the internet?

Tags: bash, scripts, updates, root, automation

I would like to auto update my system & store apps whenever I am connecting to the internet for the the first time in the login session.

How do I do that?

The flow would be:

1. User 'X' logged into the system
2. System connected to the internet
3. When step 2. happens, Trigger the script to run as root (as it is a system update).
4. Once the execution completed with success or failure state, show a popup or alert to user with custom configured information of output & execution result state (with the general shell output as well).